# Canot apply Border.all() to BoxDecoration In Container

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add a border to a Container in my flutter widget. This is what I have tried so far

[image]

But there is an error
[image]

Does any one knows what is wrong with my code?

Comment: just remove the const keyword from BoxDecoration.

Comment: You can keep const as it increase performance, and you cannot declare Border.all() as const as const constructor can’t be assigned for a class. So You can simply create an immutable border object as example: `const Border(top: BorderSide(), left: BorderSide()))` similarly for all sides.